# Why is the third column null even though there is a decimal number?

Tags: c#

Why is the third column null even though there is a decimal number? When using the query in SQL Server, the three columns have values

```cs
matcon = new SqlConnection(Connection.Default.DataSource);
            matcon.Open();

            // recieve materials name

            matadp = new SqlDataAdapter("select DISTINCT Material from Inventory", matcon);
            mattbl = new DataTable();
            matadp.Fill(mattbl);

            //add materials name in list

             MaterialList = new List<string>(); ;
            if (mattbl.Rows.Count > 0)
            {


                numberOfList = mattbl.Rows.Count ;
                for (int L = 0; L < numberOfList; L++)
                {
                    MaterialList.Add(mattbl.Rows[L][0].ToString());
                }
```

Here the Problem. I recieved only 2 columns and the third is NULL

```cs
                for (int C = 1; C < numberOfList; C++)
                {
                    matadpC = new SqlDataAdapter("select DISTINCT SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar,Material)='" + MaterialList[C] + "' THEN Count END)as M,SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar,Material)='" + MaterialList[C] + "' THEN CONVERT(int,Amount)*CONVERT(int,Count) END) as Amount , SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar,ConsumablesMaterial)='" + MaterialList[C] + "' THEN Consumables END) as Consumables  from Inventory", matcon);
                    mattblC = new DataTable();
                    matadpC.Fill(mattblC);

                    amountc = Convert.ToDecimal(mattblC.Rows[0][2].ToString());
                    Label labelf = new Label();
                    labelf.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, margin, margin, margin);
                    labelf.Name = MaterialList[C];
                    labelf.Text = MaterialList[C] + ": (total)" + mattblC.Rows[0][0].ToString() + " - " + mattblC.Rows[0][1].ToString() +"   - "+ MaterialList[C] + " Consumed: " + amountc.ToString();
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelf);

                }

            }



            matcon.Close();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what's happening here but it looks like this could be combined into a single query (using a GROUP BY) that you could test in SSMS. It would be a significant improvement in performance, too, from N+1 queries down to 1.

Comment: Plus, the query in the loop should be using parameters but you wouldn't have to do that if you combined them because there would be no turnaround.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a viable answer with the current state of the question. It depends on your data and you haven't provided any of it yet.

Comment: Please use consult [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to describe only the details essential to understanding the problem.

Comment: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 1):

arrays start at 0 not 1

```
   for (int C = 0; C < numberOfList; C++)
```

Comment: While this is a good point, the question is about why the third column is null.

Comment: because you are looking at columns 2, 3, 4 not 1, 2, 3?

Comment: started from 1 because [0] has white-space and the materials name start at position 1

Comment: Sounds like bad data.

Comment: It's also worth noting that without an ORDER BY clause, the row order cannot be assurred, so skipping the first row may work now but it may skip actual data on future runs. You should be filtering it out with an appropriate predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need add [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause in end of your query

```
select DISTINCT SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar,Material)='" + MaterialList[C] + "' THEN Count END)as M,SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar,Material)='" + MaterialList[C] + "' THEN CONVERT(int,Amount)*CONVERT(int,Count) END) as Amount , SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar,ConsumablesMaterial)='" + MaterialList[C] + "' THEN Consumables END) as Consumables  from Inventory GROUP BY(<Add here necessary Inventory columns as Inventory.ColumnNameA, Inventory.ColumnNameB...>)", matcon);
```

Comment: When use this code the result will be :

`(NULL    NULL   NULL)
(NULL    NULL   1.3562)
(3           3000     NULL)`
---------------------------------------
But I want  the numers in one row like :
`(3           3000     1.3562)`

Comment: Update your question by providing more details about your tables and a sample of the data they have. What is the result you get when you run the commands in your database?